# How to use aggregate functions when using recursive query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

On multiple iteration on a recursive query in postgresql, I have got the following result when i run the  below query

```
WITH recursive report AS ( 
  select a.name, a.id, a.parentid, sum(b.id) 
    from table1 a 
         INNER JOIN table2 b on a.id=b.table1id 
   GROUP by a.name, a.id, a.parentid 
), report2 AS (
  SELECT , 0 as lvl 
    FROM report 
   WHERE parentid IS NULL 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT child., parent.lvl + 1 
    FROM report child 
    JOIN report2 parent 
      ON parent.id = child.parentid 
) 
select * from report2
```

[image]

I want to sum the **count** column with the top most level, so my output should be like below,

[image]

What is the best possible way to get it.

Comment: I don't understand your description of the result.

Comment: You need to calculate a path during your recursion to accomplish this.  Also, your recursive output looks more like the input that goes into a recursive query.  Is the only thing you calculated using recursion the `level` column?

Comment: yes i just calculated the level column only from the query. @MikeOrganek

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe -- I want to add the value of count coulmn and group it to the main parent lane i.e. level = 0

Comment: so why archive = 7 ?

Comment: Please share your recursion code by editing your original question, and I can show you how to calculate a path array that will allow you to get your totals.

Comment: @FatFreddy - For the archive , we have data till 2nd level. Check the last row(depth or array) and its parent is the child of Archive

Comment: @FatFreddy  It's because `depth or array` rolls up through `started but not finished`.

Comment: @MikeOrganekn This is my query I am using 

WITH recursive report AS (
 select a.name, a.id, a.parentid, sum(b.id) 
 from table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b on a.id=b.table1id
 GROUP by a.name, a.id, a.parentid
),
report2  AS( 
 SELECT *, 0 as lvl
    FROM   report
    WHERE  parentid IS NULL

 UNION ALL

 SELECT child.*, parent.lvl + 1
    FROM   report child
    JOIN   report2 parent ON parent.id = child.parentid
)
select * from report2

Comment: I added the query to your original question.  Also, you did not `@` me correctly as there is an extra `n` at the end of my name, so I was not notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you calculate a path during recursion, like so:

```
WITH recursive report AS ( 
  select a.name, a.id, a.parentid, sum(b.id)  -- Is summing b.id the right thing here?
    from table1 a 
         INNER JOIN table2 b on a.id=b.table1id 
   GROUP by a.name, a.id, a.parentid 
), report2 AS (
  SELECT report.*, 0 as lvl, array[report.id] as path_array
    FROM report 
   WHERE parentid IS NULL 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT child.*, parent.lvl + 1, report2.path_array||report.id
    FROM report child 
    JOIN report2 parent 
      ON parent.id = child.parentid 
) 
select * from report2;
```

Do you really mean `sum(b.id)` and not `count(*)` in the `report` CTE?

You can get the `sum` of `count` for your top levels using this query as the main query from your recursion:

```
select t.name, sum(r.count) as total_count
  from report2 r
  join table1 t
    on t.id = r.path_array[1]
 group by t.name;
```

Comment: Hello @Mike Organek You are really an awesome.. I got what i looked for. Very much Thank you for your valuable answer  .. Hope this time I typed your name correctly. :-)

Comment: I actually needed the count(*) only. Question was mistakenly updated from the comment which I given earlier. When I use count(b.id), I got the answer correctly. And I verified the same. Its 200% correct.