# Store tree in SQL with fast transitive mean

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, data-structures, tree

So, my problem is that I need to store a tree structure in an SQL database.
There are 2 types of nodes: NODES and LEAVES. Nodes store no data. Leaves store a single number.
Sometimes the new nodes and leaves may be inserted (it is okay to insert them in the middle of some hierarchy), other times they may get deleted (both leaves and nodes), they may also get updated (for example, switch parent node to another one ot get new data, for leaves).
My primary goal is to be able for each node to tell the mean value of its leaves (transitive included, i. e. leaves of child nodes, leaves of chld of child, e.t.c).
So far I have came up with multiple ideas, but I do not find them really efficient and maintainable in the means of inserting and deleting data:

1. Using PostgreSQL's `ltree` module. It allows for quick checking of a node belonging to some leaf, including, transitively. Using that we can select based on leaf being a child of a current node and then calculate a mean value. However, it seems to me, there may be issues with updating. For example, when a node switches its parent we will need to update every child node and leaf (including transitive ones) so we do not match them when, for example, try to search for leaves belonging to node before the previous parent of the switching node. (hope doesn't sound too complicated)
2. The second approach I've considered is using arrays in each node and leaf to store all its ancestry (like parent, grandparent, grand-grand, e.t.c). This, actually, shares the same problem considering switching parent. Moreover I have doubts about the perfomance of searching in arrays, since the hierarchy may become really deep).
3. Basic approaches like storing direct parent link / childs array seem not perfomant enough to me, since I will have to execute `n-1` queries, where `n` is the depth of the tree

So now I'm wondering if there any other ideas, I have not thought of. I believe, there must be a better approach!

Comment: What's the size of the tree you want to prepare for? Please indicate at least; number of nodes, number of leaves, depth, avg. number of children per node.

Comment: @TheImpaler, I believe it should be perfomant enough for the depth up to 10 levels (really orst case scenario), each level having up to 10-15 and those edge nodes will have up to 10,000 cases. To make things more real-world, this is some kind of marketplace, where I have different categories, subcategories, sub-sub... and many goods. So the value of the leaves is the price of the good. For each node (category) I need mean prices of its goods. Goods may get updated, categories may change parent category. Overall it can grow infinitely. Hope it helps!

Comment: Does your idea #3 rule out a recursive query?

Comment: @MikeOrganek hmm haven't thought about it yet
Quick googling looks like it's gonna get only 1 request, sounds good
Can you, please, provide a small example, if possible? For simplicity lets consider only 3 fields: id, parentId, data. So i'd like to get all the leaves, from which, I suppose, I can get calculate mean

Comment: Here is an example similar to your problem statement:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/63412403/13808319